# cp command in yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

i'm launching a glassfish pod on my Kubernetes cluster, and i'm trying to copy some .war files from a folder that's on my host, but the command cp always seems to fail.

my yaml file:

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: glassfish
spec:
# replicas: 2
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: glassfish
 strategy:
  type: Recreate
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: glassfish
  spec:
   containers:
   - image: glassfish:latest
     name: glassfish
     ports:
     - containerPort: 8080
       name: glassfishhttp
     - containerPort: 4848
       name: glassfishadmin
     command: ["/bin/cp"]
     args: #["/mnt/apps/*","/usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/"]
     - /mnt/apps/
     - /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/
     volumeMounts:
     - name: glassfish-persistent-storage
       mountPath: /mount
     - name: app
       mountPath: /mnt/apps
   volumes:
   - name: glassfish-persistent-storage
     persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: fish-mysql-pvc
   - name: app
     hostPath:
      path: /mnt/nfs
      type: Directory
```

I'm trying to use the following command in my container:

```
cp /mnt/apps/* /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy
```

What am I doing wrong?

So far i've tried to do it with the /*, without it, using /*
When i use apps/* i see "item or directory not found", when i use apps/ i get "directory ommitted", i need only whats in the map, not the map itself so -r doesn't really help either.

Comment: what is the failure? do you get any error message?

Comment: when i dont use the * i get "directory ommited", if i use the * i get "file or directory doesn't exist"

Comment: Ok. Edit your question to be more explanatory, add the whole command of what you try to do please

Comment: added it to the question

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note here:

1. If you want to copy a direcyory using `cp`, you have to provide the `-a` or `-R` flag to `cp`:

> ```
>  -R    If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory and the entire subtree connected at
>        that point.  If the source_file ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than
>        the directory itself.  This option also causes symbolic links to be copied, rather than indirected
>        through, and for cp to create special files rather than copying them as normal files.  Created
>        directories have the same mode as the corresponding source directory, unmodified by the process'
>        umask.
>
>        In -R mode, cp will continue copying even if errors are detected.
> ```

2. If you use `/bin/cp` as your entrypoint in the pod, then this command is not executed in a shell. The `*` in `/path/to/*` however is a shell feature.
3. initContainers do not have `args`, only `command.

To make this work, use `/bin/sh` as the command instead:

```
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - cp /mnt/apps/* /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/
```

Comment: when i enter the above version of /bin/sh i get the following: /bin/sh: 0: cant open cp....

Comment: After trying a bit more, i am now at the point where my pod doesn't even give logs anymore when i try kubectl logs <pod>, but it keeps crashing with /bin/sh

Comment: Hi, my mistake! initContainers do not have `command` and `args`, they only have `command`. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: My bad as well, we can't use initContainers here since it is copied to local path not PV...

Comment: i've tried using only command, and copied the cp command to make sure i dont make an error, but it throws up another crashloop

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

here is correct command to execute:

```
command: ["sh", "-c", "cp -r /mnt/apps/* /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/ && asadmin start-domain --verbose"]
```

With your cp command you effectively overwrite legitimate required command to start everything. You can see original one (running ok without your cp command) if you inspect that container. Initially, container is started with:

```
...
"Cmd": [
    "/bin/sh", 
    "-c",
    "asadmin start-domain --verbose"
],
...
```

simply adding it after the copy command solves your issue.